# Using page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField not working when deployed, but works fine on localhost

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on an HttpModule that injects a hidden field on every page.  I have a PreRequestHandlerExecute method that attaches my Page_PreRender to the page's event handler, and everything runs fine.  Then I call:

```
page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("HiddenFieldName", stateFormatter.Serialize(Value));
```

in the PagePreRender.

This works fine on localhost when debugging, but when I deploy to our IIS7 server in classic mode, there is no hidden field in the page.

I have even tried to attach a PageInit method to inject an actual ASP HiddenField object into the page's form and then set the value in the PagePreRender, but that hidden field doesn't should up when deployed either (though it works on localhost as well).

Any ideas?

Comment: So, instead of implementing this in an HTTPModule, I overrode the PreRequestHandlerExecute in the global.asax and it works when deployed.  I would still like this to be in a separate httpmodule that can be imported into multiple projects instead of a global.asax

Comment: Looks like my HTTP Module isn't being loaded.  I'm registering the module with my web.config, but when deployed on my IIS7 server running in classic mode, it doesn't load the http module